# different solutions depending on contour integration versus residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have a complex function I would like to integrate over. I can use two approaches and they should give the same solution.
If I want to find  the contour integral $\int_\gamma \bar{z} d z$ for
where  $\gamma$ is the circle $|z-i|=3$ oriented counterclockwise I get the following:

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \overline{i+3 e^{i t}} d\left(i+3 e^{i t}\right)=\int_0^{2 \pi} 3 i\left(-i+3 e^{-i t}\right) e^{i t} d t=18 \pi i $

If I directly apply the Residue Theorem, I would get

$$ \int_\gamma \bar{z} d z = 2\pi i \text{Res}(f,z=0) = 2\pi i $$.

I am wondering why they don't give the same solution.